# Artifactory and source files

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, artifactory

I'm using for the first time artyfactory like tool of repositories managment. I have some project (also modular) that uses maven like tool of project managment and the sources of these projects are hosted on a svn server.

A few day ago we decided to pass to artifactory. Now I confused on like manage the source files with artifactory.

For example, suppose to create a project "first-project", initially this project has 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT version. I have also a folder on my svn server for this project and I uploaded it on artifactory. At a certain point I decided to release it, the its version now is 1.0.0, I tag it on svn and deploy it on artifactory.

Summarizing for this project I have two artifacts on artifactory and I have two folder in my workspace that are shared with a svn server.

Now I want to ask you, is this the correct way to manage snapshot and realease version?
Can artifactory store also the source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with the same configuration...

When you release your application artifactory recognize the version and put the jar on releases library...

This is the scenario:

I'm working with a new application, the starting version is 0.1-SNAPSHOT..

I've it in the trunk of SVN, in the workspace and on Artifactory after the first deploy (the jar uploaded)

Well now... i'will have to make the first release...so i use the maven release plugin (prepare and perform) or something else... and the situation changes like this:

On SVN i will have in the trunk my SNAPSHOT (which i use to develop new fatures) and inside tags folder, my first release...

On artifactory i will have both the jar, the SNAPSHOT and the Release-one..

In my workspace i should have only the SNAPSHOT cause, if I have to develop is not correct to use the released project, you don't have to commit on that...

Sure...if you have released the 1.0 you will have to increase the SNAPSHOT version...

Is inconsistent to continue working with the 0.1-SNAPSHOT or 0.9-SNAPSHOT if you have released the 1.0

I hope this helps...

Comment: Your reply has clarified many things I, but now I want to ask you this: after the first realease i have to continue to develop new features on my project, At a certain point I notice that in the released version there are some bug. In this case What do I do?

Comment: First, before you release your application, it should be hard tested to reduce at minimum the bug possibilities, however could certainly happen that a release includes bugs..so you should develop some fixes on the trunk(on the SNAPSHOT) and make a new release (1.1 or maybe 2.0) that does not include the previous bug...is it clear? To synthesize, you should fix those bug and make a new release...Never modify the 1.0 release...after an application is released that released version should be immutable...

Comment: ok, but in the trunk I could have added also new functionality that  I don't want put in the new realease (1.0 or maybe 2.0), how can I exclude them?

Comment: Clearly all that I'm saying depends on the context...but generally in this case the choice is different..if you choose to not include the new features in the first release, in the moment you add features you create a branch and start develop this features on the branch, instead in the trunk start the bug fixing activities, after you resolve the bugs, make the new release (1.2) from the trunk (that does not include the new features)....after testing the new release when you are sure that no bugs left, you can merge the branch with the trunk and continue to develop on the trunk...

Comment: Just to be precise...When I said before it depends on the context...it means that (depending on context) could be right the inverse solution...new fautures on the trunk and bug fixing on a branch created from the tag... when bugs are fixed release the branch and continue to develop on the trunk new features...

Comment: But when you say "new features on the trunk and bug fixing on a branch created from the tag", Can you give me an example on how can i manage it in a smart way using a maven-realease plug-in?

Comment: This one to create a branch from a tag and from the trunk---> <http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html>  and this one for the general documentation of maven release: <http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin> The release process consist on two step, the prepare (replace snapshot dipendency and commit on tag) perform (check out tag, build and deploy on remote repository)